# Pasting accented characters using TinyMCE paste plugin crashes IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, crash, tinymce, non-ascii-characters

We are using the TinyMCE control to handle formatted text in our web application.  We support accented characters in our application.  However, pasting accented characters into a field between other text (accented or not) causes IE8 to freeze and it must be restarted.  If we paste into an empty field it works fine, if we paste at the beginning or end of the field it does not crash.  It only crashes when pasting between other text.  This does not happen in FireFox or Chrome.

I have identified the "paste" plugin as the problem, but we need to use this plugin to properly paste text from MS word into the application.  I have not been able to find anything in TinyMCE's documentation or on their forum.  I have posted a few things on their forum and I have not received any responses.

Does anyone else have this problem and a possible solution (other than don't use IE)?

Comment: where is hte problem in the past plugin? do you get any js errors?

Comment: I don't know where the problem is in the plugin or even if there is a JavaScript error because the browser hangs and needs to be restarted.

Comment: can you use firebug or an other developer browser tool?

Comment: I have tested the application in Firefox and there is no error.  Firebug had nothing to report.

Comment: what does the IE developer tool tell you?